# Mean by month on R stacked raster

Tags: raster, r, aggregation, stack

I work with MODIS NDVI rasters in 2016. I have 23 rasters stacked in one object. I have 2 raster by month. I would like the average by months and conserve a raster for each month.

```
ndvi.stack <- stack(result)

# attribute name for each raster stacked
idx <- seq(as.Date('2016-01-17'), as.Date('2017-01-03'), '16 day')
names(ndvi.stack) <- idx

dim(ndvi.stack)
#[1] 302 268  23
## Set up color gradient with 100 values between 0.0 and 1.0
breaks <- seq(0, 1, by=0.01)
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "lightgreen"))(length(breaks)-1)

##plot
levelplot(ndvi.stack,at=breaks, col.regions=cols, main="NDVI 2016")
```

[image: NDVI for each 16 days]

I would like to get something like that 
[image: rasterViz package visualization]

Comment: this is very helpful, just wondering at what point do you need to multiply the NDVI by 0.0001? Is this before of after you make the means and do you only need to do this for the NDVI or for the composite day of the year also? Thanks, Anya

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798389/sum-nlayers-of-a-rasterstack-in-r/31800679#31800679) a more generic way with the `raster` package using `stackApply()`.

```
#get the date from the names of the layers and extract the month
indices <- format(as.Date(names(ndvi.stack), format = "X%Y.%m.%d"), format = "%m")
indices <- as.numeric(indices)

#sum layers
MonthNDVI<- stackApply(ndvi.stack, indices, fun = mean)
names(MonthNDVI) <- month.abb

## Set up color gradient with 100 values between 0.0 and 1.0
breaks <- seq(0, 1, by=0.01)
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "lightgreen"))(length(breaks)-1)
levelplot(MonthNDVI,at=breaks, col.regions=cols)
```

Et voilà
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The most accurate solution to create monthly composites from these 16-day best value images would be to take into consideration the accompanying 'composite_day_of_the_year' scientific data set (see also [MOD13A1 V006](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13a1_v006) product description). For a rather straightforward solution, please have a look at `temporalComposite` from **MODIS** and, in particular, the example included in the documentation. Using MOD13A1.006 from 2016, the code to create monthly mean value composites goes like this:

```
library(MODIS)

## download and extract required layers
runGdal("MOD13A1", collection = getCollection("MOD13A1", forceCheck = TRUE),
        begin = "2016001", end = "2016366", extent = "Luxembourg",
        job = "temporalComposite", SDSstring = "100000000010")

## import 16-day ndvi
ndvi <- list.files(paste0(getOption("MODIS_outDirPath"), "/temporalComposite"),
                   pattern = "NDVI.tif", full.names = TRUE)

## import corresponding composite day of the year
cdoy <- list.files(paste0(getOption("MODIS_outDirPath"), "/temporalComposite"),
                   pattern = "day_of_the_year.tif", full.names = TRUE)

## create monthly mean value composites
mmvc <- temporalComposite(ndvi, cdoy, fun = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

plot(mmvc[[1:4]] / 10000, zlim = c(-.1, .95))
```

[image: mmvc]

Remember to set 'localArcPath' and 'outDirPath' before downloading images (see also `?MODISoptions`).

Comment: I have ever downloaded 5 years of modis images ... I would like to use it! But thank you!

Comment: I've added data download and layer extraction via `runGdal` for the sake of reproducibility only. As long as you have the initial .hdf files available, simply extract all 'composite_day_of_the_year' layers and put them in `temporalComposite()` together with the raw NDVI.

Comment: Really great to see this! Are weekly/monthly means possible with the MODIS package for other products like MCD19A2 that do not provide a daily composite?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. For daily products like MCD19A2, the `raster::stackApply()` based solution provided by @delaye is totally sufficient for creating weekly, monthly, etc. composites.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I'm making some progress with `raster::stackApply()`.