# Aggregation of MODIS 16 days data to annual data set

Tags: r, modis, aggregation

Is there a way to calculate mean annual NDVI and mean annual EVI from the time series MODIS images (2000 - 2016). I have gridded data downloaded to the local drive. Planning to use R for this work.

Comment: I don't think any answer beyond "yes, compute the mean for the data within each year" is going to be useful to you specifically unless you tell us more about the data you've downloaded - like the filenames, formats, etc etc etc. Have you read them into rasters or raster stacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in a [previous thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237272/mean-by-month-on-r-stacked-raster/237301#237301), the most accurate way to create temporal composites from raw 16-day MODIS vegetation indices (VI) layers is to make use of the accompanying 'composite_day_of_the_year' (DOY) scientific data sets. Since the last image from a particular year (eg 2015) might already contain some pixels from the following year (eg 2016), such an approach ensures that only valid pixels (ie actually originating from 2015) are included in the calculation.

The creation of yearly value composites has been made available through [**MODIS_1.1.0**](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/MODIS/MODIS_1.1.0.tar.gz). Simply install the package and have a look at the 'Examples' section in `?temporalComposite`. The function requires you to specify VI and DOY layers as either 'character' file names or 'Raster*' objects. Starting from data download and extraction), the creation of yearly NDVI (and similarly EVI) mean value composites would go as follows:

```
# devtools::install_github("MatMatt/MODIS", ref = "develop")
library(MODIS)
library(mapview)

## download and extract sample data
frc <- as(subset(franconia, district == "Mittelfranken"), "Spatial")
tfs <- runGdal("MOD13A1", begin = "2015001", end = "2016366", extent = frc,
            job = "temporalComposite", SDSstring = "100000000010")

## separate ndvi and doy layers
ndvi <- sapply(tfs[[1]], "[[", 1)
cdoy <- sapply(tfs[[1]], "[[", 2)

## create yearly mean value composites
ymvc <- temporalComposite(ndvi, cdoy, interval = "year", fun = mean)
```

[image: spplot]

Comment: `devtools::install_github("MatMatt/MODIS", ref = "mapedit")` fails with: `Installation failed: 404: Not Found`

Comment: @R.M. Thanks for pointing this out, I've edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `raster` package, if you already have a `RasterBrick` or `RasterStack` with time written to the z dimension (see `setZ`), you can simply use `zApply`.

```
library(raster)
library(lubridate)

zApply(b, by = year, fun = mean)
```